# SSMTP not sending mails "Cannot open mailhub:25" (tldr : file permissions when user is www-data)

Tags: php, docker, ssmtp

I struggled a LOT — way too much — fixing an issue with my SSMTP install so I decided to share the solution here.

I got multiple instances of php inside docker containers. Every instance should be able to send emails, but instead of installing a mail server in each docker, I've set them to use SSMTP to relay emails. SSMTP will relay emails to an exim docker ([namshi/smtp](https://github.com/namshi/docker-smtp)) which will send emails.

`(n * [PHP -> SSMTP]) -> EXIM`

I had to set `/etc/ssmtp/revaliases` and `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` according to their docs, but it worked only when I was sending emails through root, but not with PHP which is working through `www-data`.

I renamed the linked dockers so php instances and ssmtp call them by "mailhub".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question

Comment: It’s not, but why needing to close it, it’s so old.

Answer (score 9):

SSMTP was NOT giving any hint or nothing except `Cannot open mailhub:25`. After HOURS reading [SSMTP source code](https://github.com/ajwans/sSMTP), trying every possible steps to reproduce what SSMTP was doing, I finally found it...

When using `www-data`, `/etc/ssmtp` was not reachable because of file permissions. **SSMTP is SILENT** about this and never inform you that it uses its default configuration instead of an unreachable config file.

All I had to do to fix that was : `chmod 777 /etc/ssmtp /etc/ssmtp/*`

NOTE : my config files do not contain any password and I don't really care about security in this particular case, but any body who is concerned by these issues should not use 777 but may be 640 instead.

Useful commands to test your config:

- `sudo -u root ssmtp -v my.own.email@gmail.com < mail.txt`
- `sudo -u www-data ssmtp -v my.own.email@gmail.com < mail.txt`
- `/usr/sbin/ssmtp -v my.own.email@gmail.com < mail.txt`

**Content of mail.txt :**

> From: my.company@my.domain.com
>
> To: my.own.email@gmail.com
>
> Subject: test email
>
> test text

Comment: I don't know if this will fix my very similar problem, but thank you for thinking of other developers after solving your problem!

Comment: This is not sufficiently secure.  In my case, I learned that the problem was the group ownership on ssmtp.conf had changed to root:root.  After changing it back to root:mail, then ssmtp worked again.

Comment: @pauljohn32 Your answer is brilliant, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can just add your unpriveleged user to mail group:
`usermod -aG mail <username>`

And put an alias in /etc/ssmtp/revaliases 
`<username>:your_login@your.domain:mailhub.your.domain[:port]`

That's worked like a charm.

- Without a `<username>` in /etc/ssmtp/revaliases it doesn't work.
  And **don't forget relogin** by your user into the system ( must 0n ubuntu )
  **before** trying your new settings. Don't know why but it goes like that...